# Copy few lines before and after the match string in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and trying to write a script for copying 5 lines before and 5 after the matching string is found

```
import re

text_file = open(input("Input-file name : ") , "r")
fi =  text_file.readlines()

test = re.compile(r'matching character')

for i in range (len(fi)):
    if test.search(fi[i]):
        print(fi[max(0, i-5)])
        print(fi[max(0, i-4)])
        print(fi[max(0, i-3)])
        print(fi[max(0, i-2)])
        print(fi[max(0, i-1)])
        print(fi[max(0, i-0)])
        print(fi[max(0, i+1)])
        print(fi[max(0, i+2)])
        print(fi[max(0, i+3)])
        print(fi[max(0, i+4)])
```

Is there a better way than adding multiple print statements to get the output in one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the matched line is included in the 5 lines "after", then:

```
    block = fi[max(0, i - 5): min(len(fi), i + 5)]
```

will give you a list of the lines. To print the list as one block, you can do:

```
    print(''.join(block))
```

Comment: Little more help ... is there a way I can get the user input how many lines he want in a variable and use that in the block command. I  tried                      

    x = input("number of lines after the error : ")
    y = input("number of lines after the error : ")          

    for i in range (len(fi)):
     if srb.search(fi[i]):
          block = fi[max(0, i - x): min(len(fi), i + y)]
      print (''.join(block))


Thiss didnt work and gave an error stating STR and INT cant be used together

Comment: @Zoro99. The value returned by `input()` is a string. To convert it into integer, do e.g. `x = int(x)`.